# Validation stops after one error found

Tags: oracle, validation, sqlplus

I want to find all errors for each customer entered, but validation stops after one error is found.  How do I make it run through each validation?  I want the same data to be entered in the ERROR_AUDIT table twice, so the second customer has two errors, a duplicate customer number, and invalid zip.
    
    
         100001
        Ray Graduate
        834 Meadowlink
        Lewisville
        TX
        77777
     
     
        100001
        Jay Rade
        834 Link
        Lewisville
        TX
        777

```
-- check for duplicate cust_number
SELECT COUNT(*) 
 INTO v_count
  FROM cust_entry
  WHERE cust_number = t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_NUMBER;

--if current record exists, insert into the error_audit table
IF v_count > 0 THEN
  INSERT INTO error_audit 
    VALUES('XML101', USER, SYSDATE, input_file, t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_NUMBER, 
    'Customer number already exists.');
  V_VALID := 'N';
END IF; 

IF LENGTH(t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_ZIP) < 4 THEN
  INSERT INTO error_audit 
    VALUES('XML102', USER, SYSDATE, input_file, t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_NUMBER, 
    'Customer zipcode less than 4 digits.');
  V_VALID := 'N';
END IF;

IF V_VALID = 'Y' THEN
   INSERT INTO cust_entry
     VALUES(t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_NUMBER, t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_NAME,
       t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_ADDR, t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_CITY, 
       t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_STATE, t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_ZIP, 
       t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_PHONE, t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_BALANCE, 
       t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT);
 END IF;

V_VALID := 'Y'; -- This reinitializes the valid record switch.
```

Comment: You might try  
  INSERT INTO error_audit 
    VALUES('XML102', USER, SYSDATE, input_file, t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_NUMBER, 
    'Customer zipcode length is ' & LENGTH(t_tab(cur_cust).CUST_ZIP) );

Comment: The invalid customer never gets to the second validation.  It sees that the customer has an invalid customer number (it is a duplicate of the first customer), and stops checking.  I want it to check for both, and the result would be 2 entries in the error_audit table

Comment: Your code should be inserting two errors if they occur.

Comment: Do you have any unique constraints/primary keys on the audit table that would prevent multiple lines being inserted there?

Comment: Since no one could see an error, I rewrote the entire file, and it is working now.  So I don't have a clue where I went wrong.